# how to use sed/awk to do math arithmetic from a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file `test.txt` with multiple lines sharing the same pattern:

```
a:1;qty=2;px=3;d=4;

a:5;qty=6;px=7;d=8;

a:9;qty=10;px=11;d=12;
```

And I would like to write a simple terminal linux cmd using sed/awk to calculate `(2*3+6*7+10*11)/(2+6+10)`, which is `sum(qty*px)/sum(qty)`.

May I ask that, how to retrieve the value of qty and px in each line, and then use awk to store the values and do the final calculation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

One way if no empty lines:

```
awk -F"[=;]" '{x+=$3;y+=$3*$5}END{print y/x}' file
```

If empty lines present,

```
awk -F"[=;]" '!/^$/{x+=$3;y+=$3*$5}END{print y/x}' file
```

Comment: Is a regex field separator allowed in POSIX `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the most general pattern, then the following oneline should suffice

```
cat test.txt | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*[:=]//g' | awk -F';' '{ s1 += $2*$3; s2 += $2; }; END { print s1/s2; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the keys are not always in the same order, you can do

```
awk -F "[=: ]*" '{ for( i=2; i<=NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1) }
                 { num += a["px"]*a["qty"]; den+=a["qty"]}
                 END { print num/den }' file
```